# How can I use Web Bluetooth in a static, local HTML file?

Tags: google-chrome, web-bluetooth

I have a site that uses Web Bluetooth, which I would would like to use offline as a static, local file without a web server.  I've been working on it at https://picam-dashboard.glitch.me/ (based on Adafruit's example https://adafruit-webbt-playground.glitch.me/).  In addition to stripping out some features and crudely adding others, I basically dumped the JS and CSS into a single HTML file for portability.  I know there are all kinds of horrible practices going on here, but right now I'm just trying for proof of concept.

The page runs fine when served via Glitch or a local server, but if I open the file directly, the promise returned by `device.gatt.connect()` never resolves.  If I run `device.gatt.connect()` in the console, it fails with the error `DOM Exception: GATT operation not authorized`.

(I'm testing in Chrome 92 on Windows and Android.)

I'm aware that Web Bluetooth will only run in a secure context, but the static page will still allow scanning for devices and can correctly get the device addresses so that doesn't seem to completely be the problem.  That being said, the success when using a local web server makes me think it's still a security context issue.

Am I missing something obvious or is there another way to utilize web Bluetooth from a static file (without a local server)?

Thanks for any feedback/thoughts/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded locally the HTML file from https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-disconnect-async-await.html and tried it out with success. I can see the Web Bluetooth browser picker, select my Bluetooth device, and `device.gatt.connect()` resolves properly.

It works both for `file://` and `content://` URLs respectively on Desktop and Android.

I wonder if your Bluetooth device does not accept multiple connections. Make sure all previous connections are closed and give it a try again.